# jenkins pipeline after run unit test karma script do not stop

Tags: docker, jenkins, karma-jasmine, angular-cli, jenkins-pipeline

I created un jenkins pipeline which run a docker container with nodeJs, karma and xvfb to run unit test.
Test are successful passed but the script never stop even with captureTimeout: 60000 and singleRun: true in the karma configuration

Where i'm wrong

```
[33m05 04 2017 16:01:54.227:WARN [karma]: [39mNo captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
[32m05 04 2017 16:01:54.260:INFO [karma]: [39mKarma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/
[32m05 04 2017 16:01:54.262:INFO [launcher]: [39mLaunching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
[32m05 04 2017 16:01:54.282:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser Chrome
[32m05 04 2017 16:01:59.120:INFO [Chrome 57.0.2987 (Linux 0.0.0)]: [39mConnected on socket /#0Rk4DaJRdDHKCHNvAAAA with id 66659056
Chrome 57.0.2987 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 2 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
[1A[2KChrome 57.0.2987 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 2 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.99 secs)
[1A[2KLOG: 'MAIN'
Chrome 57.0.2987 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 2 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.99 secs)
[1A[2KChrome 57.0.2987 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (0 secs / 1.269 secs)
[1A[2KChrome 57.0.2987 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (1.319 secs / 1.269 secs)
```

**Pipeline :**

```
        def karma = docker.image('trion/ng-cli-karma')
        karma.pull()

        try {

            karma.run(' -u $(id -u) -v ${WORKSPACE}:/app trion/ng-cli-karma ')
            karma.inside {
                sh 'npm install'

                try {
                    sh('ng test')
                }catch(err) {
                    sh 'echo TEST FAILED'
                    step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: 'report/*.xml', healthScaleFactor: 1.0])
                    throw err
                }
                sh 'echo DO SOMETHING ELSE AFTER TEST'
            }
            sh 'ls -al '
        } catch(err) {
            sh 'echo RUN DOCKER FAILED'
            throw err
        }
```

**Karma conf :**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        mime: { 'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx'] },
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'angular-cli'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
            require('angular-cli/plugins/karma'),
            require('karma-junit-reporter')
        ],
        files: [
            { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            './src/test.ts': ['angular-cli']
        },
        remapIstanbulReporter: {
            reports: {
                html: 'coverage',
                lcovonly: './coverage/coverage.lcov'
            }
        },
        angularCli: {
            config: './angular-cli.json',
            environment: 'dev'
        },
        reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
            ? ['progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul']
            : ['progress'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        customLaunchers: {
            Chrome_without_sandbox: {
                base: 'Chrome',
                flags: ['--no-sandbox'] // with sandbox it fails under Docker
            }
        },
        junitReporter: {
            outputDir: './report', // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.xml
            outputFile: 'report.xml', // if included, results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName/$outputFile
            suite: '', // suite will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
            useBrowserName: false, // add browser name to report and classes names
            nameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the name attribute in xml testcase element
            classNameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the classname attribute in xml testcase element
            properties: {} // key value pair of properties to add to the <properties> section of the report
        },
        reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
            ? ['progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul', 'junit']
            : ['progress', 'junit'],
        captureTimeout: 60000,
        singleRun: true
    });
};
```

Edited: 07/04/2017
no one can help me or may be i'm not clear, My problem is when i run my jenkins pipeline 'the Run unit test' step never finished (cf screenshot) and i can't check if my test pass or not to launch the next step. I need help to known how i can stop it with command line or something else after the karma test are finished.

I try to make it with karma configuration (captureTimeout: 60000, singleRun: true) but nothing happened

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem, before in my Jenkinsfile, i used the command sh('ng test') to run test without to know exatly what's happen in background.

So i used directly the karma command

```
sh ('./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js')
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume that karma was watching for changes which is nice for development machines but not good for CI builds. If you want to avoid changing the karma config, you can pass `--watch false` as parameter to `ng test`. (Although you have `singleRun: true` I am not sure whether `autoWatch: true` will have higher priority.)

I suggest you use the docker container to execute the complete build instead of single docker-run commands.
Jenkins provides a nice abstraction to run commands inside a docker container:

```
docker.image('trion/ng-cli-karma').inside {
        stage ('load npm dependencies') {
            echo 'Load npm dependencies'
            sh 'npm install'
        }
        stage ('build') {
            echo "building"
            sh 'npm run build'
        }
        stage ('unit test') {
          sh 'ng test --progress false --watch false'
          echo 'generate test report **/dist/test-reports/*.xml'
          junit allowEmptyResults: false, testResults: '**/test-results.xml'
          echo 'end test & coverage'
        }
   ...
```